# why i receive Http 401 "Unauthorized" when i sned a notification to Blackberry push notification server?

Tags: blackberry

I copied the code that calls the BlackBerry push notification from server A to server B, but now i receive Http 401 Res. "Unauthorized" using the same credential that im using in server A.
is the IP Address filed when you request the BlackBerry credential for push to App could be the reason for this error? .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly I have sent push messages succesively from different servers. The IP was required for my registration, but the information I got back (with my credentials) stated the IP was not required. The only time I recall getting a 401 error on return was when I had made a mistake in the APPID or password.

I know this isn't very helpful, but when I have time I will try to confirm that I can push from multiple servers and update this answer.